# Conkeror enable fullscreen on youtube

Tags: permissions, youtube, html5, conkeror

I'm using `conkeror version 1.0~~pre-1+git150730-1` on debian stretch. When I go on youtube the fullscreen button is not clickable (grey). For some reason youtube prefers HTML5 over flash. The flash player is installed though. I suppose it has something to do with the permissions. I already opened the `permission-manager` but couldn't figure out how to add the fullscreen permission. The examples only cover popups, cookies, images and install permissions as far as it says in the template file. Are there any permisions not shown there? Where can I get more information?

When I go to [youtube.com/html5](http://youtube.com/html5) I get support for HTMLVideoElement, H.264, WebM VP8 but not for Media Source Extensions, MSE & H.264 and MSE & WebM VP9. I don't know if this info helps.

When I go to other streaming sites fullscreen works without problems, since they use flash. Is there a way to force youtube to use flash as well?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think conkeror accepts many Firefox plugins, and there are plugins that privilege flash in youtube ([example](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-video-player/)).

Comment: @harrymc I tried but failed to install the addon you suggested. I don't think it's supported.

Comment: Not all Firefox addons work, maybe because conkeror does not support all the required API. Here is [another one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-player/). It might also be that you need an older version of the addon. You can find these by scrolling down and clicking on "Version Information" (never tried it, but it might work).

Comment: I've tried some of the older versions, but none of them installed. Neither does the other addon. 

Isn't it possible to allow fullscreen in HTML5?

Comment: conkeror might not be the best tool. You might be able to use a better player [like VLC](http://lifehacker.com/5577212/play-youtube-videos-directly-in-vlc-media-player).

Comment: Isn't vlc something different? I use conkeror to browse the web. And I'd like to be able to use it on YouTube as well.

Comment: I wonder why [this link](http://conkeror.org/YouTube) doesn't work for you.

Comment: @harrymc I am able to get into youtube mode. C-c C-f returns 'No fullscreen button found. [...]' Same with C-c C-m. 
Some other keybindings work. When I press f, I get a very strange fullscreen effect. The video resizes to the screen size but is not displayed on the entire screen but rather in the former window of the smaller video format.
I can (un)pause the video using 'k'.